# knitr in Texshop uses late R version

Tags: r, knitr, tex, rnw

Following  `http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/` I added the kntr engine, and I am able to run .Rnw in Texshop.

The problem is that the R version used is the one in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/` which is the late 2.15. I noticed this when getting an error that some libraries were not installed. They are indeed installed, but in the path of the recent R version, somewhere in `local/bin`

In Rstudio, the most recent version of R is used in the compilation of .Rnw files. Therefore, it seems the problem lies with Texshop. Any help to correct the search path?

Comment: Well, Rscript really isn't an Rstuio thing, it's an R thing. Perhaps you can use the [Rswitch](http://r.research.att.com/) utility to change which version of R is invoked when you call `Rscript`. Or maybe [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) can help.

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks for your answer! Just to be clear, RStudio "loads" the most recent version of R, no issue here. The problem is when I compile Rnw files in Texshop with knitr - the R version is not the same as in RStudio. When I run `which Rscript` is terminal I get `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` which matches with the path of the recent version.